# This code works without free() involved. Is this okay?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ft_strlen(char *str)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (str)
        while (str[i])
            i++;
    return (i);
}

void ft_append(char **str, char c)
{
    int len = ft_strlen(*str);
    char *str2 = *str;
    char *newstr = malloc(len + 2);
    int i = 0;
    if (len != 0)
    {
        while (i < len)
        {
            newstr[i] = str2[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    newstr[i] = c;
    newstr[i + 1] = '\0';
    *str = newstr;
    //this line causes *str to also be freed.
    //        free(newstr);
}

int main()
{
    char *str;
    ft_append(&str, 'x');
    ft_append(&str, 'y');
    ft_append(&str, 'z');
    printf("str = %s\n", str);
}
```

This code works as intended. `printf` returns `xyz`. But I am wondering if it is okay for me to not use `free()` in `ft_append`? I always read that when a new array is created using `malloc` I should follow up with `free` when I am not using the array anymore, but when I type `free(newstr)`, `str` also gets free resulting in `printf` returning nothing.

Comment: (1) "works as intended" [No it doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/35b3YooMK). You are trying to add something to `str` which is not initialised. This is undefined behaviour. Use the sanitizer option and/or valgrind to check your work. (2) No it is not OK to omit `free`. However you need to `free` things **after** you are done with them. You cannot `free(newstr)` *inside* `ft_append` because you are returning this memory for further use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters the program has undefined behavior because the pointer `str` defined in main was not initialized and has an indeterminate value.

```
char    *str;
```

So at least calling the function `ft_strlen` for such a pointer

```
int     len = ft_strlen(*str);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Also the function `ft_append` produces memory leaks because early allocated memory the address of which is stored in the pointer `str` is not freed in subsequent calls of the function.

You need initially to set the pointer `str` to NULL

```
char    *str = NULL;
```

and within the function `ft_append` to use the function `realloc` instead of `malloc`.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t  ft_strlen( const char *str )
{
        size_t   i = 0;

        while ( str[i] ) i++;

        return i;
}

int     ft_append( char **str, char c )
{
        size_t len = *str == NULL ? 0 : ft_strlen( *str );

        
        char    *newstr = realloc( *str, len + 2 );

        int success = newstr != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {
            newstr[len] = c;
            newstr[len + 1] = '\0';
            *str = newstr;
        }

        return success;
}

int     main( void )
{
        char    *str = NULL;

        ft_append( &str, 'x' );
        ft_append( &str, 'y' );
        ft_append( &str, 'z' );

        printf( "str = %s\n", str );

        free( str );
}
```

Comment: You need to realloc `len + 2` every time.

Comment: @KenY-N You are wrong.

Comment: `( *str )[len + 1] = '\0';` writes to the `len + 2`th byte.

Comment: @KenY-N Oh, I am sorry. You are right. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its a problem as your program will have memory leaks , where information you have put in memory will stay there even after your program has exited.

look at a program called Valgrind [Website](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) and Install it.

Run `valgrind --leak-check=yes nameofyourprogram` and it will indicate how much memory is leaked .

The problem is `malloc()` allocates memory randomly which means that once the memory leak happens its hard to trace and delete unless you restart you computer ,A lot of memory leaks can cause out of memory issues if this was a big project.

In Short

```
free(newstr);
newstr=NULL;
```

Also use `((len +2 )* sizeof(char))` Instead so the malloc is char size based

Answer (score 0):

At the end of `ft_append` the old value of `*str` must be freed:

```
if (str2 != NULL) {
    free(str2);
}
```

You must decide whether `*str` is allowed to be NULL.

But consider doing ft_append twice. then there are three values of `*str` the first two needing to be freed in `ft_append`. After calling ft_append, you lose the old `*str`.

The other issues are already addressed in the older answers.